# How to find out the interval within which probability of sample mean lying within $\pm a$ units of population mean is $0.95$ using Python?

Tags: inference, scipy, numpy

I am a beginner in the field of statistics and data science, so request you to treat me kindly.

I have to solve the following problem in python:

> Suppose the population variable $X$ is $\text{N}(3, 0.3)$ and $n = 20$. How large an interval must be chosen so that the probability is $0.95$ that the sample mean $\overline{X}$ lies within $\pm a$ units of the population mean $\mu$?

I know 68% data lies within 1 standard deviation ie 2.7 to 3.3. 95% data lie within 2 standard deviations ie 2.4 to 3.6.

My code:

```
 from scipy.stats import norm
  a,b = norm.interval(alpha=0.95, loc=3, scale=0.3)
  print(b-a)
```

Output:

```
1.1759783907240324
```

But the answer (b-a) is incorrect as its not matching the predefined answer of the hidden test case.

On printing a,b values I got:

$$a = 2.412010804637984$$

$$b = 3.587989195362016$$

May be I did not get the question correctly or I am not computing in a proper way.

#Attempt 2

```
from math import sqrt
u=3+(1.96*(0.3/(sqrt(20))))
l=3-(1.96*(0.3/(sqrt(20))))
u-l   # 0.2629615941539756
```

#Attempt 3

```
from math import sqrt
u=3+(1.645*(0.3/(sqrt(20))))
l=3-(1.645*(0.3/(sqrt(20))))
u-l   # 0.22069990937922945
```

## Attempt 4

Assuming the question wants half width of the interval, I divided the answer by 2 but its still showing incorrect...

```
from math import sqrt
    u=3+(1.96*(0.3/(sqrt(20))))
    l=3-(1.96*(0.3/(sqrt(20))))
    (u-l)/2   # 0.1314
```

## Attempt 5

```
from math import sqrt
        u=3+(1.645*(0.3/(sqrt(20))))
        l=3-(1.645*(0.3/(sqrt(20))))
        (u-l)/2   # 0.11
```

Answers not matching hidden test case

Kindly suggest me what to do.

Comment: μ=¯ ± Z(σ/√n). So Z=1.96, n=20, sigma=0.3, but ¯ is sample mean. μ is population mean.So ¯ will be 3 or μ will be 3?

Comment: I have added 2 attempts.

Comment: In the statement of the problem, are you looking for the full width of the interval or the half-width, $a$ in terms of being within $\pm a$ of the population mean?

Comment: I think the question wants full width...moreover I also divided the answer by 2 and checked....its still showing incorrect

Comment: I have attempted 2 more times. Assuming  the question asked for half width of the interval, I divided the difference by 2. Still its showing incorrect....Am I approaching in the right direction towards the question? Kindly suggest.........

Comment: I will be highly obliged if anyone kindly replies....

Comment: Trying different code fragments to see if the expected answer miraculously appears is a frustrating approach and it doesn't generalize beyond an artificial testing situation.  Instead, work out the solution algebraically and *then* do the calculation.  BTW, this is *not* a confidence interval problem: it is a probability calculation, pure and simple. cc @Bruce.